# How can I validate request arguments in SimpleFormController - Spring MVC

Tags: validation, spring-mvc, httprequest

I want handle update operation using SimpleFormController. 
URL to this controller looks as follow:

http://example.com/updatesomething.html?id=42

I wonder how to validate on the begining if object with the given id (42) exists, because I want display 404 error page when id is incorrect and stop processing.

Thanks in advance for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should put in your method the attribute `HttpServletResponse response` like this

```
public void handleRequest(Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
  if(!objectExists(id) {
    response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
  }
  //do stuff
}
```